# Как правильно обращаться к элементам структур, объединенных в массивы?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Исходим из того, что переменным в структурах присвоены значения. При компиляции возникает ошибка "request for member ‘base_reg’ in something not a structure or union". Я понимаю, что делаю что-то неправильно с указателями, пробовал разные варианты, но не могу понять как сделать верно. Мой код:

```
struct element {
    char name[15];
    uint16_t reg;
    uint16_t value;
};    

struct {
    uint16_t reg;          
    uint16_t total;
    struct element eq[500];
} state_1;

struct {
    uint16_t base;         
    uint16_t total;
    struct element eq[200];
} state_2;

size_t * all_state [] = {NULL, &state_1, &state_2};

int main (void) {
    fprintf(stdout, "all_state = %i\n",all_state[1]->reg);
}
```

Как корректно обращаться к элементам в данном случае? Например reg.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что Вы хотите иметь анонимные структуры и уметь к ним обращаться? В Вашем случае без хаков это не возможно. А сама ошибка возникает, потому что во время выполнения есть указатель на size_t , а самих данных о структуре уже нет....

Comment: То есть у меня не получится объединить в единый массив разнородные структуры?

Comment: объединить то можно, но только нужно будет знать, что там внутри лежит, что бы корректно обратиться. Вон ниже @Harry наваял плохой пример:) Какую задачу решаете?

Comment: Задача - своего рода база данных о состоянии большого количества условно датчиков. Они сами по себе разнообразны по типу и сгруппированы в разные по составу и размеру группы (групп много). Можно было объединить все во вложенные структуры (сделать типа дерева), но я пытаюсь найти решение с массивами чтобы упростить поиск и произвольный доступ к конечным датчикам и не использовать указатели на следующий/предыдущий элемент.

Comment: Ваши две анонимные структуры отличаются только размером массива. Может стоит использовать malloc/free?

Comment: К сути вопроса это не относилось, поэтому я упростил. Реально структуры сложнее - там больше разных типов элементов, больше самих групп и их вложенность. При этом запись/чтение в структуры происходит параллельно, а еще по запросу извне вся инфа передается в одном сообщении. Впрочем, внизу @Harry мне понятно объяснил почему не работает мой код и в каком виде он может заработать. Буду искать еще искать варианты :) Благодарю за отзывчивость!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала - вы хотите передавать в массив указателей на `size_t` указатели совершенно иного типа, да еще и разных типов одновременно. Такое можно разве что сделав указатели на `void`, с последующим обязательным (и верным!) приведением типа. Да и сами типы структур `state_1` и `state_2` у вас безымянны...

Словом, конечно, можно вот так:

```
struct element {
    char name[15];
    uint16_t reg;
    uint16_t value;
};    

struct state_1 {
    uint16_t reg;          
    uint16_t total;
    struct element eq[500];
} state_1;

struct state_2 {
    uint16_t base;         
    uint16_t total;
    struct element eq[200];
} state_2;

void * all_state [] = {NULL, &state_1, &state_2};

int main (void) {

    fprintf(stdout, "all_state = %i\n",((struct state_1 *)all_state[1])->reg);
    fprintf(stdout, "all_state = %i\n",((struct state_2 *)all_state[2])->eq[10].reg);
}
```

Но получается что-то сверхсложное, так что скорее всего, неверное (в смысле самогО решения, а не конкретного кода).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ и пример кода. Я понял причину ошибки.